# understanding Inheritance and Polymorphism

Tags: inheritance, polymorphism

My question is regarding Inheritance and Polymorphism.

I have a class **A** which is the super class. Classes **B** and **C** extends **A** and are subclasses.

Now i have a function in other class(not A or B or C) that takes argument of type **A**. So polymorphism allows us to pass the argument as **A** , **B** or **C** to that function. Now in that function, inorder to access **B**'s properties, i have to typecast the received argument to **B**.

Is type casting a good programming technique ? If not what is the use of polymorphism here ?

Thanks.

Comment: the benefit is code resuse and providing different behavior. that s why it s called polymorphism anyway.

Comment: Do you mean that in your method, you want an object of type **A** (and thus also its subclasses), but if the object happens to be of type **B** you want to access properties that are specific to **B** (i. e. that are not available in **A**)?

Comment: You might want to look at the Visitor or Strategy patterns as alternatives to examining the class, casting, and using if statements to handle different classes.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Typecasting is only useful if you know what to cast into.

The use of polymorphism here is that the method in the other class can be written in a generic way, and a single piece of code can thus operate on different types, which, though, have some interface (class A) in common.

So... typecasting is (depending on language culture) a very bad practice. Use of polymorphism is preferred (depending...), such as creating a different method with signature `->(B)`, taking an argument of type B.

**Update**: added Java pseudocode

```
class A { int m() {} }
class B extends A { int b() {} }
class C extends A {}
class $ { 
  static void x(A $$) {} 
  static void x(B $$) {}
}
public class P {
  public static void main(String[] a) {
    $.x(new A()); //calls $::x(A)
    $.x(new B()); //calls $::x(B)
  }
}
```

Comment: So is it good if i use instanceof operator on the argument and typecast to B if it is of type B ?

Comment: Yes, that should be safe, but separate methods are preferred for clarity/beauty.

Comment: If i create a different method with signature B, then whereever i am calling the method i need to check the type of argument and call the method accordingly. Isnt that more complex ?

Comment: No, the language does it automatically for you! That is the whole point of polymorphism, that you can have methods with the same identifier (name) but different signature (argument types), and the right one is called automatically, even if one type contains the other (the narrower one is chosen)! ... At least, that's how it works in any proper programming language.

Comment: Got it. Thanks but if i have two methods, am i not making a duplication of code with adding a little bit of additional information  in the second method?

Comment: Then the practice is to make a third method, with the common code, and call it from both methods.

Answer (score 0):

I assume you want something like that (pseudo code):

```
void foo(A obj) {
    if (obj.isOfClass(B)) {
        // Access a property that B has, but A doesn't.
    }
}
```

In that case you need to typecast:

```
void foo(A obj) {
    if (obj.isOfClass(B)) {
        ((B)obj).propertyOfB();
    }
}
```

Depending on the language, there is an alternative way. In languages like Ruby and Objective-C, so-called [*duck typing*](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Duck_typing) is used very often instead of checking whether an object is of a specific type. The idea is: if it walks like a duck and quacks like a duck it must be a duck. In other words, here it isn't so important what *type* an object is of but whether it implements certain *methods*:

```
void foo(Object obj) {
    if (obj.hasMethod(quack)) {
        obj.quack();
    }
}
```

Languages in which duck typing is used frequently are usually more of a more "dynamic" nature. For example, in C++ with it's very strict type system it's almost impossible to do duck typing (AFAIK) whereas it comes pretty natural in the aforementioned Ruby and Objective-C.

Comment: I am using java. I surmise Typecasting is the only way ? Again, is typecasting a good programming technique ?

Comment: In Java typecasting is the only way. Whether or not it's good style depends on the use case. If used with thought and seldom it's not a big deal. But if you notice that you're casting over and over again you probably should rethink your class hierarchy or how to abstract things in a different way (interfaces).